# HTML5 Move Image Along Path

Tags: image, html, path

I'm trying to move a png or gif along a predetermined path inside a `<canvas>` element. Can anyone provide a few resources or code samples to get me started?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it have to be `canvas` - [animating along a path is almost trivially easy with SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/animateMotion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at this link: [https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial:Basic_animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial%3aBasic_animations) for more information, but basically your best bet is to erase the canvas, then redraw everything having moved the image, which you drew with 'drawImage'.

The x,y coordinates will change based on your path.